# What is this "Weighty stuff indeed" referring to in the paragraph?

Tags: reading-comprehension

When I read one reading passage, there was one sentence...

> In 2006, AgroParisTech also created the Ecology and Sustainable Development Network, bringing together all the heritage conservation institutions involved in eco-matters, in particular members of the International Council of Museums (ICOM) and UNESCO. **Weighty stuff indeed!**

Does it refer to the **Ecology and Sustainable Development Network**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the whole paragraph.

"Weighty" means "serious and important". And the author is saying that the creation of the (serious and important) Ecology and Sustainable Development Network which brought together (serious and important) organizations like ICOM and UNESCO, was serious and important.

Comment: Yes, I think also, it refers to the whole paragraph, as **stuff** is uncountable we don't know in particular to what thing is referring. I think by saying **stuff** they are including all mentioned things.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

it refers to the Ecology and Sustainable Development Network.

Comment: Hello Jeck,  can you expand a little,  in particular, why do you feel that it doesn't refer to "the creation" or the bringing together of these organisations?  What is the sense of "weighty" when applied to this network?

Comment: Hello Mr James K. Why are you saying that it refers to the "creation" or bringing together.

Comment: I think, as you said, with the meaning "serious and important", it refers to: institutions involved in eco-matters, members of the ICOM and UNESCO

Comment: This answer would be improved with a  fuller explanation of **why** the referent is to the Network and not to other parts of the paragraph, or indeed to the whole paragraph.